# Passing # values with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get weinre working via Ajax by calling this on dom ready:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#hutber',
    dataType: "script",
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(data){
        c(data.status);
    },
    success: function(data){
        c(data);
    }
});
```

Now, this is what is being sent:

```
 http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js?_=1381476442102
```

Which means that, for me to debug i have to use a randomly generated ID. I have tried this also: `url: 'http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js?_=hutber',` Just shooting in the dark.

So, am i write in thinking that the `#hutber` isn't being correctly sent with the request?

**Edit**

Just a quick thought, using $.ajax means that I am loading a script dynamically via a http request. As mentioned by Quentin you cannot pass `#vars` as these are client side. It occured to me however that I could pass the pass if I added the element into the body as if it were there on page load:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute("src","http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#hutber");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Now, things should work out a little better, can't test this theory with a mobile phone however. But fingers crossed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and No. You are right in thinking that `#hutber` not being sent with the request, but you are wrong in thinking that this is incorrect.

The fragment identifier portion of a URL is handled purely client side so should never be sent to the server.

If you want to attach data to a URL for the server to process, then use a query string (starting with a `?` character and not a `#` character). If you have both a query string and a fragment identifier then the query string must come *first*.

jQuery will generate a query string for you if you include a `data` property to the object you pass to `ajax` (if you are using GET, as you are here).

```
data { "_": "hutber" }
```

Comment: Yep, these were my exact thoughts. I have tried passing as data but with no luck. Now its time to take it up with the phonegap people I do believe :)